# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "cancan"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

Am using spree 2.0.3 and I want to install the forem (forum engine ) gem version 0.0.1 
when I run bundle install I got this :

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "cancan":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (= 2.0.3) ruby depends on
      cancan (= 1.6.8) ruby

    forem (>= 0) ruby depends on
      cancan (1.6.10)
```

Comment: You will need to roll back one of the gems to a version that satisfies the version dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem , had to use an earlier version of cancan for forem and it worked fine .